# Issue with loading multiple properties files with Spring <util:properties /> when the list of files is a parameter

Tags: java, spring, config, configuration-files, properties-file

We need to load multiple properties files together and use them as one source of properties. `<util:properties>` allows you to pass a comma separated list of files and everything works fine so far. So, the following is good:

```
<util:properties loaction="conf/file1.properties,conf/file2.properties,abc-*.properties" />
```

However, in our case, the list of properties file is not fixed and it comes from another master properties file that is loaded before. We want to pass that list to `<util:properties>` as a parameter but it doesn't work.

```
<util:properties location="${allPropertiesFiles}" />
```

Where `${allPropertiesFiles}` is defined as

```
allPropertiesFiles=conf/file1.properties,conf/file2.properties,abc-*.properties
```

This fails because of commas in the list of files. It treats them as one single file name and throws FileNotFoundException.

I wonder at what point Spring tries to split the files by comma and it looks like that it happens before resolving ${allPropertiesFiles}. For example if I do as below it works fine, but that is not a practical solution for us as we don't know how many files are included in that list.

```
<util:properties location="${propFile.location1},${propFile.location2},${propFile.location3}" />
```

UPDATE:

It seems to be a Spring issue with processing and splitting with ',' before resolving the property value in `${...}`. I even tried using Spring EL to split it but it fails again with parsing the valid EL, because it first breaks it based on ',' then evaluates the expression. Below example fails with EL parse exception:

```
<util:properties location="#{'${allPropertiesFiles}'.split(',')}" />
```

FYI this observation is with Spring 4.2.x. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution/workaround to my question and would like to share it here.

The bean parsers of `util:properties` and `context:property-placeholder` split the given string value for `location` property by `,`. It happens way before property resolution occurs. Therefore if you want to pass a comma-separated list of properties files to these beans it just won't work.

So, instead of using `<util:properties>` I decided to use `PropertiesFactoryBean` directly and set the location as a parameter. This fixes how  the bean definition is built in spring, beacuse it uses Spring default bean parser. Then I provided a custom version of Spring `ResourceArrayPropertyEditor` which converts a `String` to `Resource[]`. The property editor handles comma-separated strings while converting to `Resource[]`.

Here is my context xml now:

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomEditorConfigurer">
        <property name="customEditors">
            <map>
                <entry key="org.springframework.core.io.Resource[]" value="com.mycompany.CustomResourceArrayPropertyEditor"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean> 
    <bean id="allPropertiesFromFiles" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
            <property name="locations" value="${propertiesFile.locations}" />
    </bean>
```

And here is my custom `PropertyEditor`:

```
public class CustomResourceArrayPropertyEditor extends ResourceArrayPropertyEditor
{
  private final ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver;

  public CustomResourceArrayPropertyEditor()
  {
    this(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver());
  }

  public CustomResourceArrayPropertyEditor(ResourcePatternResolver resourcePatternResolver)
  {
    super(resourcePatternResolver, null);
    this.resourcePatternResolver = resourcePatternResolver; 
  }

  @Override
  public void setAsText(String text)
  {
    String pattern = resolvePath(text).trim();
    String[] resourceNames = StringUtils.commaDelimitedListToStringArray(pattern);
    List<Resource> resourceList = new ArrayList<Resource>();
    try {
      for (String resourceName: resourceNames)
      {
        Resource[] resources = resourcePatternResolver.getResources(resourceName);
        for (Resource res: resources)
          resourceList.add(res);
      }
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not resolve resource location pattern [" + pattern + "]", ex);
    }

    setValue(resourceList.toArray(new Resource[0]));
  }
}
```

The other workaround that I could think of was to create a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to visit beans and update bean definitions of `util:properties` and `context:propery-placeholder` to simply use `TypedStringValue` for `locations` property as opposed to `String[]`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to surround your variable value with double quotes?
In a small test, this worked like a charm:

ApplicationContext:

```
<bean id="test" class="de.de.proptest.Test">
    <property name="p" ref="props" />
</bean>
<util:properties location="${props}" id="props" />
```

I have 2 properties files, a.properties with content:

```
a=1
```

and b.properties with content:

```
b=2
```

With the JVM argument

```
-Dprops="file:/home/dominik/sandbox/proptest/a.properties, file:/home/dominik/sandbox/proptest/b.properties"
```

I get the following output (cut to the interesting points):

```
Mar 11, 2017 1:32:11 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from URL [file:/home/dominik/sandbox/proptest/a.properties]
Mar 11, 2017 1:32:11 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from URL [file:/home/dominik/sandbox/proptest/b.properties]
Test [p={b=2, a=1}]
```

Comment: You needed double quote because you pass the list of properties files as a jvm arg and there is a space after comma in your list. My list comes from another properties file and if I surround it with "" it becomes part of the property value.

Comment: Second, I tried your example and it only works for me if the list is passed as a jvm arg with Spring 4.3.x. Earlier versions of Spring (e.g. 4.2.x) still fail because of comma in the list. We are on Spring 4.2.x now and we cannot upgrade at this time. Third, your example fails when I tried to pass the list from a properties file which is loaded by `<context:property-placeholder>`. It looks like Spring 4.3.x handles jvm arg better, not sure why. Please let me know if I am wrong.